# Is there a Powershell interface to read messages from MQ?

Tags: powershell, ibm-mq

I'm looking at writing a collector to read log messages off an MQ queue. I could have someone write Java or C# code, or I can write it in Powershell. Big question is can I actually? I haven't seen anything that talks about using MQ as an input source to Powershell. It seems like it would fit the model from a "pipeline" perspective...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SupportPac MO74](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24017698) is a Powershell interface and it's been updated to at least v8.0.0.2.

Comment: I thought M074 was just for admin. That's what the basic description reads. I downloaded it and it sure does enable processing MQ queues and messages. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So, if you want to get the message from MS queue you can use msmq cmdlets. [Check this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn391735(v=wps.630).aspx)

In the other hand if you want to read it from a websphere queue try [MQ Modules](http://www14.software.ibm.com/cgi-bin/weblap/lap.pl?popup=Y&li_formnum=L-SBRY-79KGEK&accepted_url=ftp://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/integration/support/supportpacs/individual/mo74_v2.0.1.zip)

Similarly if you want to try with some other queues I assume they should have an API. You can load the dll thru relection and use it in powershell.